# Clauses structure as quenched random matrix for random $k$-SAT problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, phase-transition, random-k-sat, max2sat

In the Section III of [Statistical mechanics of the random K-SAT model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9606215.pdf), the clauses structure of random $k$-SAT problems are expressed as $M \times N$ quenched random matrix where the numbers of variables and clauses are $N$ and $M$ respectively.

I would like to know when a random matrix becomes quenched. I would also like to know the implication of a random matrix not being quenched on the structure of the $k$-SAT problem.